# Shorten Form Fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, formfield

Is there a way to shorten a form field?
Here is an example of what I have:

[image: form field example]

These are text fields that will have a maximum of 6 characters in each box. I want to make them smaller so they don't stretch across the page and take up room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the textboxes have a css class `ms-long` and this class has a width property fixed to `386px`. If you want to update the css for specific textboxes you can write JavaScript/jQuery.

Example:

```
$("input[id^=CustomTextBox]").removeClass("ms-long").css("width","50px")
```

The `CustomTextBox` is my field name.